# <span> with "float: right" inside "white-space: pre"

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

The following HTML:

```html
<div style="white-space: pre">
  long time; <span style="float: right;">// know C?</span>
</div>
```

renders differently in WebKit and Gecko. With WebKit, the contents of the span remain on the same line as the preceding text, but with Gecko, they are moved to a new line.

**Which behaviour is correct, and why?**

Comment: Firefox also moves to a new line with `white-space: nowrap`.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have another try at this answer...

The `white-space` pre directive interprets white-space literally. Line breaks, spaces and tabs are displayed by the browser (br tags are also seen as line breaks). So

```
<div>   hello

world</div>
```

...displays as

```
    hello

world
```

The float:right directive takes the element out of the normal flow of text and positions it to the right of it's container, indicating text and elements should wrap around it.

Firefox will fill the available space horizontally, so the floated div goes onto the next line. Chrome does not choose to do this and keeps the floated element on the same line (though both divs are displayed as block and therefore the full available width). This explains your difference. See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/k5aueocr/

Since the white-space:pre directive is telling the browser to literally interpret each character subsequently found (as it might display if you viewed the source, minus the tags), throwing in a span that floats to the right is likely to lead you into trouble. Neither is behaving incorrectly, it is a consequence of mixing together elements of CSS that aren't really meant to be mixed.

Comment: I don't follow - why does this make both behaviours correct?

Comment: Specifically, where does the newline come from in Gecko?

Comment: Why does Firefox "fill the available space horizontally" when `white-space: pre` is present, but not when it's not?

Comment: the DIVs are display block which fills the available space. The two statements are contradictory, one is telling the browser not to wrap text under any circumstances, the other is telling the browser to wrap everything around a floated element. Both browsers are obeying the two directives in the best way they can.

Comment: What should I do instead if my intention is to show a block of code (hence the `white-space: pre`), and on one line, right-align a comment (hence the `float: right`) that pertains to code earlier in the line?